# How can i run a check on a MySQL database for a FB ID, & other personal data so only a certain page is shown when revisiting?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I have created a Facebook App that i need people to only enter their data to once.

It's all working and the database is being populated, but i need to make sure people don't keep coming back and re-entering their data endlessly.

What's the best way to check if the user has already submitted their data ?

The signed_request could still have been submitted and their data not entered so i need the check for both to work.

Ideally the PHP would just check for FB ID + other data, and only display a confirmation / thankyou page.

Currently my php to send to the database is:

```
class Users_Model extends CI_Model {
    protected $_name = 'users';

    function add($id,$key,$value) {
        $data = array(
           'id' => $id,
           'name' => $key,
           'value' => $value
        );

        return $this->db->insert($this->_name, $data); 
    }
    function update($id,$key,$value) {
        $data = array(
           'value' => $value
        );

        $this->db->where(array(
           'id' => $id,
           'name' => $key
        ));
        return $this->db->update($this->_name, $data); 
    }

    function exists($id,$key=null) {
        if($key == null) {
            $this->db->where(array(
            'id' => $id
            ));
        } else {
            $this->db->where(array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $key
            ));  
        }

        $query = $this->db->get($this->_name);
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function remove($id) {
        $data = array(
           'id' => $id,
        );

        return $this->db->delete($this->_name, $data); 
    }

    function all() {
        $query = $this->db->get($this->_name);
        $results = array();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach($query->result() as $row) {
                $results[]=$row;
            }
        } 
        return $results;  
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

> What's the best way to check if the user has already submitted their data ?

Check if you already have a record for the user’s Facebook id in your database.